# Wordpress plugin to notify all users when there is a new comment

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, comments, notifications

I was wondering if anyone knew of a plugin that notified all users when an new comment was made. At the moment it only notifies the author of the post.

Cheers.

Comment: Belongs to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this one
[Comments Notifier](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comments-notifier/).

From Wordpress extension site: "For those of us who need more than one email address to be notified, no solution existed. Until now. Comments Notifier was developed to address this problem."